# Issue creating a 2 card hand out of a 52 card deck for blackjack~for Python

Tags: python-3.x

Just a heads-up: I'm rather new to python
Anyhow, this is how I set up my deck:

```
#THIS IS THE DECK ITSELF
signs = ["spade","hearts","club","diamond"]
num=['A','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','J','Q','K']
deck = [(j,i) for j in num for i in signs]

#Step 1. creates 2 random 2-card hands (you and dealer) 
#and shows you your hand and only one card of dealer's hand
import random
def create_hands(deck):
    random.shuffle(deck)
    print ("You got:")
    print (deck[0][0], "of", deck[0][1])
    print (deck[1][0], "of", deck[1][1])
    print ("Dealer has:")
    print (deck[2][0], "of", deck[2][1])
    print ("unknown")
    player_hand = (deck[0]+deck[1])
    return player_hand
```

Afterwards, I would enter:

```
create_hands(deck)
```

and this would be the random output that is different every time due to shuffle function (there is also a print statement but I didn't include it):

```
('10', 'diamond', '2', 'diamond')
```

Now, this is basically what the list player_hand is, but when I then proceed to put in this to check:

```
player_hand
```

it outputs:

```
('4', 'club', 'J', 'spade')
```

I'm confused because shouldn't player_hand return the same value as the create_hands function, assuming I only ran create_hands(deck) once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your

```
player_hand
```

has local scope that is generated randomly, while

```
create_hands
```

has global scope and you access it externally - moreover, each call generates different outcome, so every time you will be testing either one of them you will get different result from

```
random.shuffle(deck)
```

Comment: How do you suggest I solve this so that player_hand is equal to what is returned out of create_hands?

Comment: Yes, you care only about what the function returns, as what will be within the function may differ next time, so just disregard it.